Transformation of contraints given non-invertible transformation of variables
Given the transformation $Ax = y$ and constraints $Cx \le d$, how to obtain the resulting constraints on $y$ when $A$ is rectangular with unknown rank? I'm thinking along the lines of using the pseudo-inverse of $A$, but I am stuck here.
The problem arises in volume computation of a polyhedron defined by $S = \{ y ~|~ Ax = y,~ Cx \le d \}$ where $Cx \le d$ defines a bounded convex polytope. It seems like I can compute  the volume in $x$-space using this MATLAB package, but I do not know how to obtain the volume in $y$-space.
Any guidance on the transformation of the constraints will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

The individual constraints may lose their meaning after the transformation. Think of a cube in 3-space defined as the intersection of 6 half-spaces where A is orthogonal projection onto a plane that is not parallel to any of the cube's faces. The boundary of the projected polytope is a hexagon defined by the transformation of a subset of the edges of the cube, not by the intersection of individually projected half-spaces (all of which project onto the full plane).
Therefore your best strategy is to triangulate the original polytope and to apply the transformation $A$ to its simplices (in particular, its vertices) separately.
